# Efficient algorithm to detect all 1-cuts in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a connected graph G = (V, E), I want to find all of the 1-cuts. A 1-cut is just a single edge whose removal splits G into 2 connected components.

The algorithm I'm using right now is to remove each edge in turn and then use DFS to check whether its two endpoints are in the same connected component. The runs in O(E(V + E)) time. This is already faster than the best algorithm I can find in the min-cut literature from Nagamochi, Nishimura, and Ibaraki (1998), which takes O(VE(V + E)) time. Their algorithm is valid for all min-cuts of any size. I only need mine to be valid for 1-cuts.

Does anyone know of a better algorithm out there somewhere? Another feature of my use case that might be useful is that the graphs I work with tend to have very small feedback arc sets. If I had an algorithm whose run time depended on the size of a feedback arc set, that would also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all of the biconnected components in the graph (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component).  The wikipedia article outlines the classic Hopcroft/Tarjan algorithm that can do this in linear time.

Merge biconnected components that share a vertex, and then each edge that connects different components is a 1-cut.

The common name for a 1-cut is a bridge (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory))